# My Drop Down Menu goes sideways in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a drop menu that works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in ie. The sub menu appears underneath the main menu, but it displays sideways. How do I fix it?

The site url www.umvaonline.org

code for menu

```
<li class='top'><a href='blog/'>News/Blog</a>
                        <ul class='item'>
                            <li><a href='/blog/category/news/exhibition-listings/'>Exhibition Listings</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/blog/category/news/opportunities/'>Opportunities for Artists</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/blog/category/news/workshops-classes/'>Workshops & Classes</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='top'><a href='index.php?page=journal'>Quarterly Journal</a>
                        <ul class='item'>
                            <li><a href='index.php?page=submission'>Submission Guidelines</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/blog/category/archived-journals/'>Archived Journals</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

css

div.topnav { height:40px;margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:20px;}
    div.topnav ul {z-index:10000;padding: 0 1px;     
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    display: inline-table;}
    div.topnav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }
    div.topnav ul li {  
    height: 100%;   
    float: left; 
    font-family: arial, verdana, helvetica; 
    font-size: 95%;}
    div.topnav a {
        float: left;

        height: 40px;
        line-height:  40px;
        text-align:center;
        background-image: url('umva_images/umva_button.png');
        padding-left:12px;
        padding-right:12px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;

        color: silver;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px black;

        transition:color .25s ease;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-decoration:none
        }
    div.topnav ul.item{display:none}
    div.topnav li.top:hover ul.item {display:block}
    div.topnav a.left {border-top-left-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px}
    div.topnav a.right {border-top-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px}

    div.topnav a:hover { background-image: url('umva_images/umva_button_hover.png');color:white}
    div.topnav a.current { background-image: url('umva_images/umva_button_hover.png');color:white}







    div.topnav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;    
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black

    }
    div.topnav ul ul li {
        float: none; 

        position: relative;

    }

        div.topnav ul ul li a {
            background: #5f6975;
            color: #fff;
            font-size:90%;
            width:auto;
            height:25px;
            line-height:25px;
            text-align:left;

        }   
            div.topnav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #5f6975;
            text-decoration:underline;

            }
    div.topnav ul ul li a {

            } 
    div.topnav ul li.left  {border-top-left-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px}
    div.topnav ul li.right  {border-top-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-right-radius:5px}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check out if this is working for you - add float:none; to div.topnav ul ul li a.
Just tested in IE10 and Firefox and works for me. Though there is no float set for this element, it inherits float: left from div.topnav a.

Comment: @MattStacey Glad that helped you. I'll take a look at why this caused only problems for IE and improve the answer, but main task was to provide something that fixes your problem (especially because the site is already live). All the best.